# Get array of a specific attribute of all objects from an array of objects

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array containing a set of an object with many attributes. I want to get the values of specific attributes as a list in a simple way.

I do know that I can make a list of each attribute and save them into individual lists as follows.

```py
attr = (o.attr for o in objarray)
```

But as there are a lot of attributes and these need to analyzed using plots, distributions etc. this is not an efficient way.

In my case, I am analyzing an array of 'Structure' objects which has attributes like lattice constants, position of atoms etc. And the object has functions to get distance, angles, etc. which when we give the index of atoms will return the corresponding values. What I want is to get a list of values (which may be an attribute like lattice constant or an output of a function of the object like distance between two atoms) each corresponding to each of the structures in the array. Making an individual list for each of the values needed (as mentioned above) is less efficient as a lot of such lists may need to be made and the values needed may differ depending on the purpose.

What I need is to get a list of values by something in the manner of:

```py
objarray[a:b].attr
```

which can be used easily for plotting and other functions. But this doesn't work and gives an error:

```py
[ERROR] 'list' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

**Alternately**, is there a way to make an array of objects which treats objects in the above mentioned way.

Comment: What specific attributes do you want? Please [edit] your question and specify them.

Comment: `np.fromotfunc` is the handiest tool for iterating through an array of objects. It's a bit faster than list comprehension,  But working with a list of these objects might be fastest.

Comment: @martineau I have edited and detailed my question.

Comment: @hpaulj Speed is not my intent. As I may need a lot of such values and these may differ for each purpose, making a list each time I need one is not an efficient way.

Comment: That's still too vague and it's unclear how this relates to `numpy` arrays. It would be very helpful if you included code in your question that at least created something similar to an array of objects you would want to get the attributes from.

Comment: This is not related to numpy arrays. The array of objects is just any array/list of objects. There was a mention of numpy just because the array of objects I used was a numpy array. I have edited the question and removed the tag for clarity. Sorry if it created confusion. I think what I needed has been answered below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function for this purpose.

```
>>> my_object.my_attribute = 5
>>> getattr(my_object, 'my_attribute')
5
```

To create the numpy array as you would want:

```
def get_attrs(obj, attributes):
    """Returns the requested attributes of an object as a separate list"""
    return [getattr(obj, attr) for attr in attributes]

attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
attributes_per_object = np.array([get_attrs(obj, attributes) for obj in all_objects])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think getattr() was the function I needed. But what I asked was not to get a list of attributes. I asked for a specific attribute for all objects. I have suggested an edit. ihave changed the function as:
def get_attrs(all_objects, attribute, args=None): 
    if(args==None):
        """If the requested attribute is a variable"""
        return np.array([getattr(obj, attribute) for obj in all_objects])
    else:
        """If the requested attribute is a method"""
        return np.array([getattr(obj, attribute)(*args) for obj in all_objects])

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired from the answer of @energya using the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function. As that answer makes a function to get a list of attributes of a specific object, while the question was for getting a list of one specific attribute for all the objects in the array of objects.

So using getattr function,

```
>>> my_object.my_attribute = 5
>>> getattr(my_object, 'my_attribute')
5
```

For getting a numpy array of a specific attribute of all objects:

```
def get_attrs(all_objects, attribute, args=None): 
    """Returns the requested attribute of all the objects as a list"""
    if(args==None):
        # If the requested attribute is a variable
        return np.array([getattr(obj, attribute) for obj in all_objects])
    else:
        # If the requested attribute is a method
        return np.array([getattr(obj, attribute)(*args) for obj in all_objects])

# For getting a variable 'my_object.a' of all objects
attribute_list = get_attrs(all_objects, attribute)

# For getting a method 'my_object.func(*args)' of all objects
attribute_list = get_attrs(all_objects, attribute, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for something similar and this is how I did it.

```
 low = 0
 high = 10
 x = [objarray[i].some_attr for i in range(low, high)]
```

Probably there's a better way.